# When i minimize the page, body color not filled entire window

Tags: html, css

My problem is that the red color does not fill the entire window when I view it in a browser. I want it to use 100% `height` of the space available. I think the `body` and `html` `width` isn't working, I've also included a CSS reset on my page.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    body {
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    .container {
        width:100%;
        background-color:#F00;
        float:left;
    }
    .inner-div {
        width:980px;
        background-color:#00F;
        margin:0px auto;
        height:200px;
        color: #FFF;
        font-family: arial;
        padding: 19px;
        margin-bottom: 22px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-div"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-div"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use html,body{height:100%}

Comment: `<style>` element goes in either the `<head>` or the `<body>`.

Comment: @MIkeJ. I've looked at your website and the best suggestion that I can give you is to restructure your HTML and don't use `<tables>`.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is working fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/s3bjkqj4/8/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
<style>
    html,body {    
        margin:0 auto;
        height:100%;
    }
    .main { width:100%; 
        Height:100%;
        background-color:#F00; 
        float:left;
    }
    .container,.container1 { 
        width:98%; 
        height:40%;
        padding:1%;
        margin:0;
    }
    .container { 
        background-color:orange; 
    }
    .container1 { 
        background-color:green; 
    }
    .inner-div ,.inner-div1{
        background-color:#00F;
        height:98%;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-div"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-div1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I need different backgorund color for every container